# Two gcc clang errors, does not compile

Tags: c

The two clang errors are given using `gcc` to compile the program `file2.c` in the Terminal:

```
file2.c:8:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main(){
^
file2.c:22:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'print' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    print("This will print to screen \n\n"); 
    ^
2 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_print", referenced from:
      _main in file2-d54df1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Both of the warnings are fine---the program should still run. What exactly is the error?

Here is the program `file2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int globalVar = 100;

main(){

    char firstLetter = 'D';

    int age = 38;

    long int superBigNum = -327670000;

    float piValue = 3.12158;

    double reallyBigPi = 34234324234;

    printf("\n");

    print("This will print to screen \n\n");
}
```

Comment: The complains are very clear already. Also, this is clang, **not** gcc! So the tag and your text are wrong. (let me guess: you use OS-X.). The error is actually not even from the compiler at all  All this is clearly written in the messages. As any compiler/linker would have to complain, this is not even related to a specific.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand the OS-X comment. I am using the incorrect compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  main(){
^ int is required here. for warning 1

 print ("This will print to screen \n\n");
      ^ function is printf not print, this is the reason, you are getting linker error, Try fixing it.
```

Comment: Ah, I'm blind. I see now. 

However, `int main()` is not actually required. The program still compiles.

Comment: its just a warning. as default return type is int, if you do not specify it.

Comment: Since C99, Non-prototpye-style function declarators have to generate a warning and at least since C11 they are tagged for future obsolescense, i.e. they will be enforced in a future standard (they are already by many coding standards). Howver, even after your answer, it is no correct signature.